# Inner Map function not working - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to display 8 sports in a list and display it's status participated when user already participated. Display a button when user not participated.But i didn't succeed it with the inner map function

```
{this.state.sports.map(function(sport, index){          
      return(
          <div>
                <li key={index} style={{ listStyle:'none' }}>
                    <h4>{ sport.name }</h4>
                </li>
                {this.state.join_sports.map(function(sport1, index){                        
                    return (
                        <div>
                        {sport._id === sport1.s_id ?
                            <span>Participated</span> :
                            <button className="btn btn-info btn-xs">Participate</button>
                        }
                        </div>
                    )
                }.bind(this))}
        </div>
      );
}.bind(this))}
```

Comment: What is the exact issue with the inner `.map()`?

Comment: Participated button repeating 8 times

Comment: May you please post the data held by `sports` and `join_sports`?

Comment: It seems to be fine, can you please show us the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this and simplify it with some ES6 syntax and some pseudo code markup

I think your map function looks like this:

```
mapSportsToUser() {
    const sports = ['a', 'b', ... 'z']//pseudo data
    const user = ['b', 'c'] //we should only show sport c and c
    return (
        <container> //not needed in 15.5+ I think
        { sports.map( (sport, sportIndex) => ( //this will generate one title for each sport
            <title>{sport.name}</title>

            //your second map iterates over the list...
            //(probably not the easiest way to do this but it should work)
            { user.map( (sportUser, userIndex) => {
                if (sportUser == sport) {
                    return <participate />  
                } else {
                    return null //don't render anything
                }
            } }
        )) }
        </container>
    )
}
```

I think you're making this really complex by looping over the everything rather than building the data in a way that makes sense from the start.

You might consider something like this:

```
structureData(listOfSports, listUserHasParticipatedIn) {
    let sportsLookup = {} //create a map
    for(let i = 0; i < listOfSports.length; i++) {//or whatever iterator you like
       const sport = listOfSports[i]
        sportsLookup[sport.id] = {
            sport: sport,
            participation: false,
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < listUserHasParticipatedIn.length; i++) {
        const user_sport = listUserHasParticipatedIn[i]
        //you might want to do a null check here
        sportsLookup[user_sport.id].participation = true;
    }

    return sportsLookup
}
```

Then you have something easier to map which looks like:

```
[{ sport: 'a', participation: false}, { sport: 'b', participation: true} ...]

....
   sportsLookup.map( lookup => { //much simpler
        return <container> {lookup.sport.name} {lookup.participation ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</container>
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

I got succeeded in the inner map looping technique. Just take a variable make it false initially and make it true when the condition is true. That's all. Thank you.

```
{   this.state.sports.map((sport,index)=>{
       let is_participate = false;
        this.state.join_sports.map((j_spt,index)=>{
            if(sport._id === j_spt.s_id[0]){
                is_participate = true;
            }
        });
     return(
        <li>{is_participate? <span>{sport.name}-- participated</span>:<span>{sport.name}-- participate </span>}</li>
     )
   })
 }
```